# GPUmat doesn't work in my matlab

Tags: matlab, installation, gpu

I want to use GPU in matlab, so I installed CUDA toolkit(cuda_6.0.37), downloaded GPUmat 0.28 version. Of course my pc has geforce 850m. I clicked 'GPUstart', and it seems working and type the 'GPUmatSystemCheck', it says CUBLAS, CUFFT, CUDART installed, but there is warning 'GPUmat and SYSTEM architecture are different.'. My pc is 64 bit. Type the GPUsingle(1) on the command window, it says

> 'Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'GPUtype'
>   class destructor: Undefined function 'GPUtypeDelete' for input
>   arguments of type 'double'.  Undefined function
>   'mxNumericArrayToGPUtypePtr' for input arguments of type
>   'GPUsingle'.'.

What should I do next? What am I missing?

Comment: 64 bit Windows or Linux? Are you sure you downloaded the correct version for your system?

Comment: 64 bit window 7 is installed.....
my pc <---> CUDA toolkit <---> GPUmat, 
All of them should be in accord? it is like the Trinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you installed the newest version of GPUmat, which is a 32 bit version, and hence there is the warning. Maybe it would help to download an older version of GPUmat, which is made for 64 bit systems. I tried it myself and at least I don't get the warning anymore. Instead I have the problem that some DLL files are not found (Invalid MEX-file
'..\GPUmat\win64\bin\GPUfullInfo.mexw64': not found). You could still give it a try and see if it works for you.